# Javascript unexpected identifier but works in console

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, syntax-error

When I create a script as such

```
    async function a(){
        return 'a';
    }
    console.log(await a());
```

The browser (Brave & Edge) gives the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Funnily enough, copy and pasting the exact same code into the debug console runs without a complaint.

Any explanation?

Comment: 1. you cannot use `await` outside an `async function` and 2. you only need `async` if you're using `await` inside

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `await` the way you are using it. `await` should be only used inside of an `async` function.

try this:

```
async function a(){
        return 'a';
    }
    console.log(a());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using await here as we are not returning a promise here. instead try this.

```
    function a(){
       return 'a';
     }
    console.log(a());
```

or this if you are learning to use async await and want to use it anyway

```
async function a(){
    return 'a';
}
const value = await a()
console.log(value);
```